# Show that G/A is a symplectic manifold with $\omega(g,f)=\mathrm{tr}[g,f]\lambda$

Tags: lie-groups, symplectic-geometry

I've never posted here and never learned much differential geometry, so sorry in advance if I'm doing something wrong.

Let $G$ be a compact Lie-group and $A$ its Cartan-subgroup. I have to show that the manifold $G/A$ is symplectic with the symplectic form $\omega(g,f)= \mathrm{tr}[g,f]\lambda$ with $[\cdot,\cdot]$ being the Lie-bracket, $f,g \in TG$ and a suitable $\lambda \in TA$.

Now my confusion already starts with the definition of ω. Isn't the trace of a commutator always zero?

I think I have to show that $d\omega = 0$ and that $\omega$ is non-degenerate, correct? Do I also have to show that $G/A$ is smooth?

$$d\omega(X,g,f)=X\mathrm{tr}[g,f]\lambda − g\mathrm{tr}[X,f]\lambda + f\mathrm{tr}[X,g]\lambda − \mathrm{tr}[[X,g],f]\lambda + \mathrm{tr}[[X,f],g]\lambda − \mathrm{tr}[[g,f],X]\lambda$$

I think I can use the Jacobi-identity for the last three terms after using that the trace is linear. But I don't know about the other terms. I also have no idea what is meant by "a suitable $\lambda$".

It would be great if someone could help me.

Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. We use MathJax here to improve readability. You may already know LaTeX, but we have [a guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you need it.